# Has anyone written a script to resolve a certain set macros?

Tags: macros

Here's the idea: Like most people, I use a lot of custom macros that are often nothing more than shortened versions of commands that I use often. This is great for me, but makes the latex cryptic for others who need to read it.

Does anyone know of a way to resolve/expand a certain bunch of macros? It could take as input a `tex` file and one or more `sty` file containing macros, and it eliminates from the `tex` file all the macros in the `sty` file, leaving a `tex` file that no longer needs the `sty` files.

Comment: You mean something like "compiling" your tex document to make it autonomous?

Comment: I would do this using Perl (or similar programming language), but for this the macro definition and usage must be streight-forward. Teaching Perl all the nuances of TeX is more or less impossible. E.g. catcode changes and other things would not be supported.

Comment: The idea is a source-to-source transformation where some macros get expanded while others are retained. (There might be a connection to so-called _partial evaluation_ of program code.) I think this would be very useful but given the complexity of TeX I doubt this can be reliably implemented outside a TeX engine itself.

Comment: A TeX based solution I just imagined would be to use a similar technqie as `listings` for syntax highlighting or `ltxdoc` for macro indexing: read the file verbatim but detect macro name by looking for ``\`` followed by letters. Then expand that macro once if it is in a list. This might need multiple passes.

Comment: @Christian Lindig: You're right that a general solution would be very difficult to implement outside of TeX. But the OP doesn't need a general solution, just something that works on a small number of macros that he's defined himself.

Comment: See also here a `sed` solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17793815/using-sed-in-bash-script-to-replace-latex-aliases

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following is a very simpleminded perl function that I use for this. apply_tex_macros($macros,$tex) takes TeX code in $macros and $tex, reads macro definitions out of $macros, and expands those macros wherever they occur in $tex. It's not completely general, but it works well enough for my application.

```
sub apply_tex_macros {
  my $macros = shift;
  my $tex = shift;
  my $orig = $tex;
  $macros =~ s/(?<!\\)\%.*//; # remove comments
  my $curly = "(?:(?:{[^{}]*}|[^{}]*)*)"; # match anything, as long as curly braces in it are matched, and not nested
  my $curlycurly = "(?:(?:{$curly}|$curly)*)"; # allow one level of nesting
  my $curlycurlycurly = "(?:(?:{$curlycurly}|$curlycurly)*)"; # allow two levels of nesting
  my $before;
  while ($macros =~ /\\newcommand{\\([a-zA-Z\-]+)}\s*(?:\[(\d+)\])\s*(?:\[($curlycurlycurly)\])\s*{($curlycurlycurly)}/g) {
    my $command = $1;
    if ($tex=~/\\$command/) {print STDERR "Warning in footex, command $command with optional arguments is not supported, in input $tex.\n"}
  }
  my $depth = 0;
  do {
    $before = $tex;
    while ($macros =~ /\\newcommand{\\([a-zA-Z\-]+)}\s*(?:\[(\d+)\])?\s*{($curlycurlycurly)}/g) {
      my ($command,$nargs,$def) = ($1,$2,$3);
      if (!$nargs) {
        $tex =~ s/\\$command/$def/g;
      }
      if ($nargs==1) {
        while ($tex =~ m/\\($command\{($curlycurlycurly)\})/) {
          my ($macro,$arg) = ($1,$2);
          my $result = $def;
          $result =~ s/#1/$arg/g;
          my $foo = quotemeta $macro;
          $tex =~ s/\\$foo/$result/g;
        }
      }
      if ($nargs==2) {
        while ($tex =~ m/\\($command\{($curlycurlycurly)\}\{($curlycurlycurly)\})/) {
          my ($macro,$arg1,$arg2) = ($1,$2,$3);
          my $result = $def;
          $result =~ s/#1/$arg1/g;
          $result =~ s/#2/$arg2/g;
          my $foo = quotemeta $macro;
          $tex =~ s/\\$foo/$result/g;
        }
      }
      if ($nargs>2 && $tex=~/\\$command/) {print STDERR "Warning in footex, command $command with more than 2 arguments is not supported, in input $orig.\n"}
    }
    ++$depth;
    print STDERR "Warning, macro expansion isn't bottoming out, depth=$depth, tex=$tex\n" if $depth>=28;
  } while ($tex ne $before && $depth<30);
  return $tex;
}
```

Comment: It's rather useful. One caveat is that no macro command should be a prefix of some other command. For instance, you can't have a macro called `\beg` (because of `\begin`).

Answer (score 1):

I've written a few scripts along these lines, though my aim has been more conversion between LaTeX and some other markup format (Markdown or some variant thereof).  I started with a simple perl script that expanded some LaTeX macros (could handle basic stuff), then a PHP program that converted some LaTeX stuff to XHTML+MathML, next a Perl script that attempted to emulate TeX (catcodes and all, so essentially teaching Perl all the nuances of TeX), and finally a style file that can be run with TeX itself and that outputs a text file (well, actually a PDF but with fixed-width fonts and no hyphenation so that `pdftotext` converts it perfectly to a text file) that is suitable for inputting to the next markup processor.

One component of my desired output is the itexToMML program which converts a subset of LaTeX mathematical output to MathML.  Therefore, one thing I've had to figure out is how to "escape" certain macros so that the *aren't* processed whilst allowing other macros to be processed.  This is sort of what you're asking for, only it works by a whitelist of macros *not* to be processed than a blacklist of macros that should be processed.

If any of the above sounds useful, feel free to contact me for more details.