# Expanding user defined macros for compatibility

Tags: macros, expansion, rendering

I have an annoying reoccurring problem. I often use user-defined macros with for example `\newcommand` in my LaTeX code. I also use LaTeX a lot in for example Jupyter Notebooks. Often Some things render fine locally, but don't render correctly anymore when hosted for example on Github. Or when I need to ask something on math.stackexchange, this becomes also quite annoying bringing over all macro definitions or manually expanding them.

I would therefore like to know if there is some way to produce a `.tex` file that has all user-defined macros expanded, so I can use the content of that document if I need cross-platform compatibility.

Example

```
\newcommand{\paren}[1]{\mathopen{}\left( {#1}_{{}_{}}\,\negthickspace\right)\mathclose{}}
\newcommand{\pda}[2]{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}
\newcommand{\pdb}[2]{\frac{\partial}{\partial #2} #1}
\newcommand{\grad}[2]{\nabla_{#2}{#1}}

Let the output layer activation be the sigmoid function and let the loss function be the mean square error.\\

\begin{align}
    \pda{l\paren{y, f(x)}}{A^{(L)}_i} ={}& \pda{l\paren{y, f(x)}}{f (x)_i}\\
    & \text{by definition}\\
    ={}& \pdb{\frac{1}{2n} \sum_{j=1}^n \paren{y_j - f(x)_j}^2}{f(x)}\\
    ={}& \frac{1}{2n} \sum_{j=1}^n \pda{\paren{y_j - f(x)_j^2}}{f(x)_i}\\
    ={}& \frac{1}{2n} 2 \paren{y_i - f(x)_i}\\
    ={}& \frac{1}{n} \paren{y_i - f(x)_i}\\ 
    \propto{}& y_i - f(x)_i\label{eq1}
\end{align}

\begin{equation*}
    \implies \nabla_{A^{(L)}}{l\paren{y, f(x)}} \propto y - f(x)
\end{equation*}


where $f$ is the function computed by the network and $g^{(L)}$ is the activation function of layer $L$.
```

This render fine locally:

[image]

But it renders incorrectly due to missing macro interpretation on Github:

[image]

Comment: this is a FAQ, in general the answer is no, obviously for simple cases you can use perl or python or whatever to expand known macros but latex never constructs such a thing internally  so there is no way you can simply output some already expanded document

Comment: I didn't think github rendered math by default at all? If you are loading mathjax then you can make the definitions available to mathjax as well.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22297/is-there-a-latex-tex-preprocessor-inliner-that-replaces-only-selected-macros-wit  or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3174/latex-macro-expander

Comment: A "mechanism" for distinguishing user defined macros from macros defined by someone else might be nice. ;-)   Besides this: How to handle situations where users use `\let` for "copying" primitives. E.g, `\let\MyRelax=\relax` - `\MyRelax` is user-defined but not a macro. How to handle situations where user-defined macros a) do not just expand but do define other macros? b), e.g., deliver character-tokens contained in their definition-text that deviate from the usual catcode-régime?

Comment: I assume an engine which copies/writes to file a "stream" of all those tokens that  (after expansion which takes place in the "gullet") reach TeX's stomach _and_ are used for building pages or adjusting TeX's parameters might be possible. The problem is: How to ensure at the time of processing that copy that everything gets tokenized  identically to the original?