# Is there a script that reads a TeX file and replaces every instance of a \newcommand?

Tags: programming

I'd like to know if there's a script that reads a `.tex` file and replace every instance of a non-standard TeX command with whatever it is replacing. I am not sure if what I want is clear but let me give an example:

Suppose the **input** is:

```
\documentclass{amsart} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\End}{End}

\begin{document}
In this lecture we'll study the ring of Endomorphisms of an Abelian group $A$.
Let's denote this ring by $\End(A)$. Throughout the lecture, $\N$ will denote
the set of natural numbers.
\end{document}
```

Then, a desirable **output** of such a script is:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\begin{document}
In this lecture we'll study the ring of Endomorphisms of an Abelian group $A$.
Let's denote this ring by $\operatorname{End}(A)$. Throughout the lecture,  
 $\mathbb{N}$ will denote the set of natural numbers.
\end{document}
```

**P.S.:** I think I had seen something to this effect but I neither remember the place nor a key word to fire up Google.

---

I meant to write that, all answers here are awesome, but I miscounted 2 for 4. :(

Comment: You want something like a preprocessor. See [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22297/is-there-a-latex-tex-preprocessor-inliner-that-replaces-only-selected-macros-wit) or [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3174/latex-macro-expander) for similar questions.

Comment: How deep do you want to go? Just one level or completely expanded?

Comment: @mrf I'd like to replace, for instance, `$\N$` with `$\mathbb {N}$`. So, basically, I'd like the script to replace `foo` with `oof` if the preamble has the line `\newcommand{foo}{oof}`.

Comment: Personally I think `perl` will be ideal for this... but are you after something in `TeX`?

Comment: [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/23920/5042) may be what you want. But you have to define yourself which macros you want replaced.

Comment: @cmhughes I am not sure I understand your question. I am willing to answer if you'll please explain it to me. And, I am asking this question mainly because I use `\newcommand` for shortening the length of font families. But, I understand that people not used to the macros will shout "what the @$##@$3%^@ is this supposed to be" when they see things like `$\N$` and so on...

Comment: Remark, there's an alternative of copying the header file into the TeX file using e.g. `bundledoc` see [expansion - Is there a LaTeX/TeX preprocessor/inliner that replaces only selected macros with their definitions? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22297/is-there-a-latex-tex-preprocessor-inliner-that-replaces-only-selected-macros-wit?noredirect=1&lq=1) .

Answer (score 28):

[image: Info]  <sup>I've been forced by the [TeX.sx chatroom mafia](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41/tex-latex-and-friends) to post my lovely, buggy, terrible, traumatic, post-apocalyptic poor man's implementation of a replacement script. `:)`</sup>

Well, sadly this won't be a TeX answer. `:)` Here's my humble attempt, with a script language I'm terrible at.

<sub>(I'm looking at you, Python!)</sub>

```python
import re
import sys

if len(sys.argv) != 3:
    print('We need two arguments.')
    sys.exit()

inputHandler = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')

mathDictionary = {}
commandDictionary = {}

print('Extracting commands...')
for line in inputHandler:
    mathOperator = re.search('\\\\DeclareMathOperator{\\\\([A-Za-z]*)}{(.*)}', line)
    if mathOperator:
        mathDictionary[mathOperator.group(1)] = mathOperator.group(2)
    newCommand = re.search('\\\\newcommand{\\\\([A-Za-z]*)}{(.*)}', line)
    if newCommand:
        commandDictionary[newCommand.group(1)] = newCommand.group(2)

inputHandler.seek(0)

print('Replacing occurrences...')
outputHandler = open(sys.argv[2],'w')
for line in inputHandler:
    current = line
    for x in mathDictionary:
        current = re.sub('\\\\DeclareMathOperator{\\\\' + x + '}{(.*)}', '', current)
        current = re.sub('\\\\' + x + '(?!\w)', '\\operatorname{' + mathDictionary[x] + '}', current)
    for x in commandDictionary:
        current = re.sub('\\\\newcommand{\\\\' + x + '}{(.*)}', '', current)
        current = re.sub('\\\\' + x + '(?!\w)', commandDictionary[x], current)
    outputHandler.write(current)

print('Done.')

inputHandler.close()
outputHandler.close()
```

Now, we simply call it:

```
$ python myconverter.py input.tex output.tex
Extracting commands...
Replacing occurrences...
Done.
```

**`input.tex`**

```
\documentclass{amsart} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\End}{End}

\begin{document}
In this lecture we'll study the ring of Endomorphisms of an Abelian group $A$.
Let's denote this ring by $\End(A)$. Throughout the lecture, $\N$ will denote
the set of natural numbers.
\end{document}
```

**`output.tex`**

```
\documentclass{amsart} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}



\begin{document}
In this lecture we'll study the ring of Endomorphisms of an Abelian group $A$.
Let's denote this ring by $\operatorname{End}(A)$. Throughout the lecture, $\mathbb{N}$ will denote
the set of natural numbers.
\end{document}
```

Limitations:

- It's my code, so beware! `:)`
- It works only with `\DeclareMathOperator{...}{...}` and `\newcommand{...}{...}`.
- No optional arguments are supported for `\newcommand`.
- The declaration must be in only one line.
- Balanced curly brackets, please. `:)`

I know that regular expressions are not suitable for parsing TeX, but they should work for very simple replacements.

[Here's a beautiful reading about regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1462474). Have fun. `:)`

Comment: Paulo, you may need to make some of your patterns non-greedy. For example, '{(.*)}' will match all of '{\N}{\color{blue} yes}', which I suspect is not what you want. '(.*?)' is the notation, I think. But even that will get you into trouble with nested braces. Regexen can't express arbitrarily recursive structures, as your link tells...

Comment: @Brent: oops sorry for the faulty regex. `:)` I'll take a better look at the Python documentation, maybe I could use make use of a lookahead feature. I trust your Python wisdom. `:)`

Comment: You could also turn {(.*)} into {([^}]*)}, which will do what I think you want, maybe more efficiently.

Comment: It might be worth considering using Python's [raw string literals](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2081708/1394393) to cut down on the ``\`` chatter: `r'\\DeclareMathOperator{\\([A-Za-z]*)}{(.*)}'`, for instance.

Answer (score 23):

By accident I came upon [`de-macro`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/de-macro), which is a Python script for such a purpose. It is included in TeX Live.

Limitation: It only affects `\newcommand`, `\renewcommand`, `\newenvironment` and `\renewenvironment`. Starred versions and optional arguments are not handled. The following is quoted from [this answer by Willie Wong to another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/152798/586), and has more details about the limitations:

> Based on the suggestion of Torbjørn T. and cfr, I looked more deeply
>   into the `de-macro` package. It works to a certain extent. The
>   following are caveats:
>
> - Unlike the what the documentation suggests, the version I have installed creates the database file `<filename>` instead of
>     `<filename>.db`. However evidently it tests for `<filename>.db` as the
>     name for the definitions database. So in its current incarnation it
>     will recreate the definitions database from scratch every single run.
>     For small documents this is not an issue. For larger documents one
>     should copy (not move!) the database to `<filename>.db` to take
>     advantage of any potential speed-up.
> - There are still some bugs to be ironed out. Occasionally it mangles preambles by inserting spurious `}` to the code. I have not yet found
>     the reason why or the trigger/MWE for it. The small test cases I tried
>     it on all worked fine in this regard.
> - Very important: as the documentation suggests, all the definitions you want swapped out must live inside a separate package ending in
>     `-private.sty`. In the main `.tex` file one must use that package.
> - Also very important: the program handles `\newcommand` and `\renewcommand`, but not the starred variant `\newcommand*` (though
>     this can be fixed by amending the regular expression a bit in the
>     python code, I suppose). This is why [my first
>     attempt](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152651/flatten-macros-prior-to-sharing-latex-file?noredirect=1#comment348431_152651) failed. (I always use [the starred variant since I learned about it
>     being best practice](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1050/119).)
> - Also very important: after removing the stars, the program threw up an error. Which I eventually figured out is due to my habit of writing
>     `\newcommand\cmdname{<replacement}` instead
>     `\newcommand{\cmdname}{<replacement>}`. That extra pair of braces is
>     important for the parsing!
> - Lastly, very disappointing for me, the program **cannot handle optional arguments.** `\newcommand{\cmdname}[2]{blah #1 blah #2}`
>     works fine, but `\newcommand{\cmdname}[2][nothing]{blah #1 blah #2}`
>     throws an exception.
>
> The problem with the star and the braces I can easily fix/workaround
>   by rewriting my macro definitions (which as you remember, will be
>   thrown away at the end anyway being the point of this exercise)
>   without the stars and adding the extra braces.
>
> The problem with optional argument handling however, currently makes
>   the program somewhat less useful for me. I can work around it for now
>   by splitting the optional and non-optional commands into two separate
>   ones. Maybe, if I have some time in the future, I will look into
>   adding support for it, after figuring out the logic of the original
>   python script.

Comment: It seems to me that this would use an example showing its capabilities, in sense of optional arguments etc.

Comment: @tohecz Never used it myself, but I can take a look later. (If anyone else have used this, feel free to edit my answer.)

Answer (score 13):

Here's a `perl` script to do the same job. It has the same limitations as Paulo's code, but works well in your test case. I don't doubt it could be improved upon `:)`

You use it in the following way

```
perl replacenewcommands.plx myfile.tex
```

which outputs to the terminal, or

```
perl replacenewcommands.plx myfile.tex > outputfile.tex
```

which will output to `outputfile.tex`

**replacenewcommands.plx**

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

# for newcommands
my @newcommandmacro=();
my %newcommandcontent=();

# for DeclareMathoperator
my @declaremathoperator=();
my %declaremathoperatorcontent=();

# for use as an index
my $macro;

# loop through the lines in the INPUT file
while(<>)
{
    # check for 
    #   \newcommand...
    # and make sure not to match
    #   %\newcommand
    # which is commented
    if($_ =~ m/\\newcommand{(.*)}{(.*)}/ and $_ !~ m/^%/)
    {
        push(@newcommandmacro,$1);
        $newcommandcontent{$1}=$2;

        # remove the \newcommand from the preamble
        s/\\newcommand.*//;
    }


    # loop through the newcommands in the 
    # main document
    foreach $macro (@newcommandmacro)
    {
      # make the substitution, making sure to escape the \
      # uinsg \Q and \E for begining and end respectively
      s/\Q$macro\E/$newcommandcontent{$macro}/g;
    }

    # check for 
    #   \DeclareMathOperator...
    # and make sure not to match
    #   %\DeclareMathOperator
    # which is commented
    if($_ =~ m/\\DeclareMathOperator{(.*)}{(.*)}/ and $_ !~ m/^%/)
    {
        push(@declaremathoperator,$1);
        $declaremathoperatorcontent{$1}=$2;

        # remove the \DeclareMathOperator from the preamble
        s/\\DeclareMathOperator.*//;
    }

    # loop through the DeclareMathOperators in the 
    # main document
    foreach $macro (@declaremathoperator)
    {
      # make the substitution, making sure to escape the \
      # uinsg \Q and \E for begining and end respectively
      s/\Q$macro\E(\(.*\))/\\operatorname{$declaremathoperatorcontent{$macro}}$1/g;
    }
    print $_;
}
```

In your test case

**myfile.tex (original)**

```
\documentclass{amsart} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\mycommand}{something else}
\DeclareMathOperator{\End}{End}

\begin{document}
In this lecture we'll study the ring of Endomorphisms of an Abelian group $A$.
Let's $\N$ denote this ring by $\End(A)$. Throughout the lecture, $\N$ will denote
the set of natural numbers. \mycommand

and \mycommand again
\end{document}
```

**outputfile.tex (new)**

```
\documentclass{amsart} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}




\begin{document}
In this lecture we'll study the ring of Endomorphisms of an Abelian group $A$.
Let's $\mathbb{N}$ denote this ring by $\operatorname{End}(A)$. Throughout the lecture, $\mathbb{N}$ will denote
the set of natural numbers. something else

and something else again
\end{document}
```

Comment: Awesome, Chris! `:)`

Answer (score 9):

This answer is a complement to [Paulo Cereda's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3094/paulo-cereda) [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/67723/344)

As it stands, the regex he uses doesn't support *nested* brackets, and, indeed, the language doesn't allow for nested, recursive structures of arbitrary depth.

That said, we can robustify the regex for one additional level of nesting, like this:

```
r"\\newcommand{\\([A-Za-z]*)}{((:?[^{}]*{[^}]*})*[^}]*)}"
**             **              |****************|
#1             #2              #3
```

Notes:

1. The Python r"..." construction for regexes is helpful because it
   doesn't need Python's *text* escaping (though it still requires
   *regex* escaping).
2. That means we only need \ to represent \ in the regex, making us
   all less cross-eyed
3. The main addition is a
       subpattern that looks for zero or more *balanced* brackets, followed
       by the tail end of the original pattern.

It's also possible to improve efficiency slightly by pre-compiling some of the regexes. Here's my adaptation of Paulo's solution:

```python
#! python.exe

import re
import sys

if len(sys.argv) != 3:
    print('We need two arguments.')
    sys.exit()

mathDictionary = {}
commandDictionary = {}

inputHandler = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')
outputHandler = open(sys.argv[2],'w')

mathpat    = re.compile( r"\\DeclareMathOperator{\\([A-Za-z]*)}{((:?[^{}]*{[^}]*})*[^}]*)}" )
searchmath = mathpat.search 
newcpat    = re.compile( r"\\newcommand{\\([A-Za-z]*)}{((:?[^{}]*{[^}]*})*[^}]*)}" )
searchnewc = newcpat.search 

print('Processing...')

for line in inputHandler:
    mathOperator = searchmath(line)
    if mathOperator:
        mathDictionary[mathOperator.group(1)] = mathOperator.group(2)
    newCommand = searchnewc(line)
    if newCommand:
        commandDictionary[newCommand.group(1)] = newCommand.group(2)
    current = line
    for x in mathDictionary:
        current = re.sub(mathpat, '', current)
        current = re.sub(r"\\" + x + r"(?!\w)", '\\operatorname{' + mathDictionary[x] + '}', current)
    for x in commandDictionary:
        current = re.sub(newcpat, '', current)
        current = re.sub(r"\\" + x + "(?!\w)", commandDictionary[x], current)
    outputHandler.write(current)

inputHandler.close()
outputHandler.close()

print('Done.')
```

I have also made it one-pass; defining a newcommand *after* using it doesn't make too much sense.

Comment: By the way, if you think from this that regex is for loonies, you're probably right.

Answer (score 6):

I wrote some javascript for expanding macros defined by `\def`, `\gdef`, `\edef`, `\xdef`, `\newcommand`, `\newcommand*`, `\renewcommand`, `\renewcommand*`, `\DeclareMathOperator` and `\DeclareMathOperator*`. You may try it [here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/zoho/ed84y/show/light/).

```js
function expandMacros(tex) {
    function nestBrackets(level) {
        var level = level || 5, re = c = "(?:[^\\r\\n\\{\\}]|\\\\[\\{\\}]|\\r?\\n(?!\\r?\\n))*?";
        while (level--) re = c + "(?:\\{" + re + "\}" + c + ")*?";
        return " *(\\{" + re + "\\}|[^\\{])";
    }    
    function getRegExp(name, macro) {
        var num = macro.num, def = macro.def, re = "";
        while (num--) re += nestBrackets();
        re = "\\" + name + "(?![a-zA-Z\\}])" + re;
        return new RegExp(re, "g");
    }
    function trimString(s) {
        return s.replace(/^ +| +$/g, '').replace(/^\{|\}$/g, "");
    }
    function extractMacros() {
        var cs = "\\\\\\w+", re;
        // \def, \gdef, \edef and \xdef
        re = new RegExp("\\\\[gex]?def\\*? *(" + cs + ") *(#\\d)*" + nestBrackets(), "g");
        tex = tex.replace(re, function(match){
            var m = arguments;
            var macro = {
                num:  m[2] ? Math.min(m[2].length / 2, 9) : 0,
                def:  trimString(m[3])
            };
            macros[trimString(m[1])] = macro;
            return "";
        });
        // \newcommand, \newcommand*, \renewcommand and \renewcommand*
        re = new RegExp("\\\\(?:re)?newcommand\\*? *(" + cs + "|\\{" + cs + "\}) *(\\[(\\d)\\])?"
                        + nestBrackets(), "g");
        tex = tex.replace(re, function(match){
            var m = arguments;
            var macro = {
                num:  m[3] || 0,
                def:  trimString(m[4])
            };
            macros[trimString(m[1])] = macro;
            return "";
        });
        // \DeclareMathOperator and \DeclareMathOperator* inside amsmath
        re = new RegExp("\\\\DeclareMathOperator(\\*?) *(" + cs + "|\\{" + cs + "\}) *"
                        + nestBrackets(), "g");
        tex = tex.replace(re, function(match){
            var m = arguments;
            var macro = {
                num:  0,
                def:  "\\operatorname" + m[1] + "{" + trimString(m[3]) + "}"
            };
            macros[trimString(m[2])] = macro;
            return "";
        });
    }
    function replaceMacros() {
        var i = 0, m, re, num;
        for (name in macros) {
            m = macros[name];
            re = getRegExp(name, m), num = m.num;
            //console.log(re);
            tex = tex.replace(re, function(match){
                //console.log(arguments);
                var args = [], result = m.def, k;
                for (k = 1; k <= num; k++) {
                    args[k] = trimString(arguments[k]);
                }
                //console.log(args);
                for (k = 1; k <= num; k++) {
                    result = result.replace(new RegExp("#" + k, "g"), args[k]);
                }
                return result;
            });
        }
    }
    var macros = {};
    extractMacros();
    replaceMacros();
    return tex;
}

document.getElementById("run").onclick = function() {
    var input = document.getElementById("input"),
        output = document.getElementById("output");
    output.value = expandMacros(input.value);
}
```

Comment: Oh, Thank you very much for something that works online! Will the link always work? (The thing about codes like this is that, they would help reduce manual labour. So, I am pretty happy with this implementation!)

Comment: In fact, the web page is hosted by [http://jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/zoho/ed84y/embedded/result/). Therefore the link will always work as long as JSFiddle website is online. You may also save the web page to your computer.

Comment: Hi I just found out about this wonderful script and its website, thanks. In case the website goes offline, how could I use this script on my machine (I have not much experience with javascripts)
Thanks