# "Expanding" locally defined commands

Tags: macros, expansion

I wrote a paper using custom ("locally defined") commands and environments (e.g. a new quote environment, loads of abbreviations, etc.). The journal requires me eliminate all non-standard LaTeX packages and commands/environments.

Is there an out-of-the-box way of doing this? I'm thinking in something like the following:

**Original document**

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand*{\myabbrone}{\textit{This is my first abbreviation}}

\begin{document}
  \myabbrevone
\end{document}
```

**Cleaned document**

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
  \textit{This is my first abbreviation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Roll that code through [`de-macro`](http://ctan.org/pkg/de-macro)...

Comment: Duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/67709/586