# Variable Width Tilde

Tags: macros, accents, variable

I wish to define a new macro, `\vartilde` say, so that `\vartilde{a}` produces the following:

- `\tilde{a}` while in inline maths mode, ie using `$ ... $`;
- `\widetilde{a}` while in display maths mode, eg using `\[ ... \]`.

Put another way, I'd like

> `$\vartilde{a} = \tilde{a}$` and `\[ \vartilde{a} = \widetilde{a} \]`.

One could think of this as a variable width tilde.

Comment: redefining `\tilde` especially with a text component isn't the best idea in the world.  for some reasons, see [Textual substitution of macros in a LaTeX file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/387960/579).  on the other hand `\vartilde` isn't unreasonable.

Comment: It's not clear: `\tilde` is not legal in text mode.

Comment: @barbarabeeton ok, thanks -- `\vartilde` isn't exactly difficult to write!

Comment: @egreg yes, fair enough, it's not 100% clear. Further, Mico has misinterpreted it also, so while it seems obvious to me it appears that you're not alone in your confusion! (clear to me as I know what I meant! =P) -- let me edit...

Comment: Thanks for your comment. If you see in my OP, I'm using `$` symbols. I didn't know about using `\(` and `\)` -- although it is a very natural counterpart to `\[` and `\]`. There is, of course, no harm to changing to `\(...\)` if necessary!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure it's a good idea.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\vartilde}[1]{\mathpalette\dovartilde{#1}}
\newcommand{\dovartilde}[2]{%
  \ifx#1\displaystyle\widetilde{#2}\else\tilde{#2}\fi
}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}% just to get it above the other one
$\vartilde{a}$
\end{center}
\[
\vartilde{a}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

See [The mysteries of \mathpalette](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34393/the-mysteries-of-mathpalette) for more information about `\mathpalette`.

Comment: Thanks very much, that's exactly what I was looking for -- I thought it would be something to do with `if displaystyle`, but didn't know how to do it.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why you feel it's not a good idea? (I am only a PhD student, yet to publish, so I appreciate insight from experienced people!) My reason for wanting to try this is the following. The standard `\tilde` is too small, I feel, particularly when used inline. However, when `\widetilde` is used inline, it either increases the whitespace between its line and the line above (which then looks very bad, I feel), or the tilde is almost closer to the line above than the symbol it is 'accenting'. Given this comment, do you still feel it would be unhelpful? Thanks :)

Comment: @SamT Beginners tend to overuse `\widetilde` (and `\longrightarrow` too), feeling that `\tilde` is “too short”. It isn't; to the contrary, `\widetilde` is often too big (like in the picture above). Your readers will be surprised seeing different tildes for the same letter.

Comment: So, ironically, I don't have much of an issue with it -- maybe I'd prefer it slightly longer, but the disadvantage caused by moving the linespacing I feel is major -- but my supervisor changed all the `\tilde`s in my document to `\widetilde`. Thank you for your comments

Comment: @SamT Somebody gets attached to their own ideas when young… `;-)`

Comment: Haha yeah =P -- thank you for your advice. Given then consensus of answers by extremely experienced people has been to not implement this, I shall follow that advice. Nevertheless, I am always trying to learn more about how TeX works -- and you in particular have been very helpful in my learning -- so I am genuinely appreciative of your explanation of how to implement this (as well as your advising me not to!) :)

Answer (score 5):

(I rewrote this answer completely after the OP clarified the posting's objective.)

Assuming you use `\(` and `\)` (rather than `$`) to initiate and terminate inline-math mode, you could achieve your objective by (a) patching these two commands so that a toggle is set to either `true` or `false`, respectively, and (b) defining the `\vartilde` macro so that it invokes either `\tilde` or `\widetilde` depending on whether the toggle is true or not.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newif\ifinlinemath\inlinemathfalse % initialize to "false"
\usepackage{etoolbox} % for \pretocmd and \apptocmd macros
\pretocmd{\(}{\inlinemathtrue}{}{}
\apptocmd{\)}{\inlinemathfalse}{}{}
\newcommand{\vartilde}[1]{\ifinlinemath\tilde{#1}\else\widetilde{#1}\fi}

\begin{document}
\centering
\( \tilde{X} \quad \vartilde{X} \quad \widetilde{X} \)

\[ \tilde{X} \quad \vartilde{X} \quad \widetilde{X} \]

\( \tilde{X} \quad \vartilde{X} \quad \widetilde{X} \)
\end{document}
```

Two asides:

- I'm not knowledgeable enough to figure out how to do this if `$`, rather than `\(` and `\)`, is used to initiate and terminate inline math mode.
- Speaking for myself, I think that using different tilde styles for one and the same variable, depending only on whether the material occurs in inline math mode or display math mode, is bound to utterly confuse your readers. (Expecting your readers to appreciate the difference between inline and display math mode might be a tad unrealistic...) I certainly wouldn't do this in my own documents.

---

*Addendum*, to address the OP's comment that using `\widetilde` for inline math material "an push the line down". AFAICT, this can only happen if you have an unusually small value for `\baselineskip`. For most Roman fonts -- blackletter fonts, such as any Fraktur-type text font, are a different matter -- the baselineskip is usually set to 120% of the nominal font size. E.g., if 10pt is the nominal font size and Computer Modern is in use, the baselineskip is set to 12pt. This should be more than enough to keep TeX from widening the interline spacing when either `\widetilde` or `\widehat` are used in conjunction with uppercase letters.

In the following screenshot, the left-hand column uses no accents, the middle column uses `\tilde` and `\hat`, and the right-hand column uses `\widetilde` and `\widehat`. AFAICT, there's no difference in the line spacing; in particular, the "wide" accents didn't modify the line spacing.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\newcommand\blurb{Once upon a time, there was \dots\ }
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{3}
\blurb $X$ $X$ $X$ $X$ \blurb $X$ $X$ $X$ $X$ \blurb $X$ $X$ $X$ $X$ \blurb $X$ $X$ $X$ $X$ \blurb $X$ $X$ $X$ $X$ \blurb $X$ $X$ $X$ $X$ 

\blurb $\tilde{X}$ $\tilde{X}$ $\tilde{X}$ $\tilde{X}$ \blurb $\tilde{X}$ $\tilde{X}$ $\tilde{X}$ $\tilde{X}$ \blurb $\tilde{X}$ $\tilde{X}$ $\tilde{X}$ $\tilde{X}$ \blurb $\tilde{X}$ $\tilde{X}$ $\tilde{X}$ $\tilde{X}$ \blurb $\tilde{X}$ $\tilde{X}$ $\tilde{X}$ $\tilde{X}$ \blurb $\tilde{X}$ $\tilde{X}$ $\tilde{X}$ $\tilde{X}$ 

\blurb $\widetilde{X}$ $\widetilde{X}$ $\widetilde{X}$ $\widetilde{X}$ \blurb $\widetilde{X}$ $\widetilde{X}$ $\widetilde{X}$ $\widetilde{X}$ \blurb $\widetilde{X}$ $\widetilde{X}$ $\widetilde{X}$ $\widetilde{X}$ \blurb $\widetilde{X}$ $\widetilde{X}$ $\widetilde{X}$ $\widetilde{X}$ \blurb $\widetilde{X}$ $\widetilde{X}$ $\widetilde{X}$ $\widetilde{X}$ \blurb $\widetilde{X}$ $\widetilde{X}$ $\widetilde{X}$ $\widetilde{X}$ 
\end{multicols}

\begin{multicols}{3}
\blurb $X$ $X$ $X$ $X$ \blurb $X$ $X$ $X$ $X$ \blurb $X$ $X$ $X$ $X$ \blurb $X$ $X$ $X$ $X$ \blurb $X$ $X$ $X$ $X$ \blurb $X$ $X$ $X$ $X$ 

\blurb $\hat{X}$ $\hat{X}$ $\hat{X}$ $\hat{X}$ \blurb $\hat{X}$ $\hat{X}$ $\hat{X}$ $\hat{X}$ \blurb $\hat{X}$ $\hat{X}$ $\hat{X}$ $\hat{X}$ \blurb $\hat{X}$ $\hat{X}$ $\hat{X}$ $\hat{X}$ \blurb $\hat{X}$ $\hat{X}$ $\hat{X}$ $\hat{X}$ \blurb $\hat{X}$ $\hat{X}$ $\hat{X}$ $\hat{X}$ 

\blurb $\widehat{X}$ $\widehat{X}$ $\widehat{X}$ $\widehat{X}$ \blurb $\widehat{X}$ $\widehat{X}$ $\widehat{X}$ $\widehat{X}$ \blurb $\widehat{X}$ $\widehat{X}$ $\widehat{X}$ $\widehat{X}$ \blurb $\widehat{X}$ $\widehat{X}$ $\widehat{X}$ $\widehat{X}$ \blurb $\widehat{X}$ $\widehat{X}$ $\widehat{X}$ $\widehat{X}$ \blurb $\widehat{X}$ $\widehat{X}$ $\widehat{X}$ $\widehat{X}$ 
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Apologies for the ambiguous question, but this isn't what I meant. I want to use an `if` statement to say "if display maths" or "if inline maths". See the edit to my OP. Apologies again

Comment: @SamT - I've completely rewritten my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for this solution, and thank you for your final aside. (I am only a PhD student, yet to publish, so I appreciate insight from experienced people!) My reason for wanting to try this is the following. The standard `\tilde` is too small, I feel, particularly when used inline. However, when `\widetilde` is used inline, it either increases the whitespace between its line and the line above (which then looks very bad, I feel), or the tilde is almost closer to the line above than the symbol it is 'accenting'. Given this comment, do you still feel it would be unhelpful? Thanks :)

Comment: @SamT - My rule of thumb is to use `\tilde` with lowercase-letter variables and `\widetilde` with uppercase-letter variables, especially if they're wider than average. E.g., I'd write `\tilde{x}` and `\widetilde{X}`, but also `\tilde{I}`. Same rule for `\hat` and `\widehat`: `\hat{\sigma}` and `\widehat{\Sigma}`. However, this is just a rule of thumb, and I don't claim that it's based on some grand optimization of a multi-dimensional typographic objective function. Plus, I'm sure fervent testimonies can be obtained from satisfied writers who'd always prefer `\tilde{X}` to `\widetilde{X}`...

Comment: That is an interesting point of view, thank you. Personally I just hate the fact that `\widetilde` inline can push the line down, so always look to use `\tilde` inline. Thank you for your comments, and for your answer on how to implement: even though I won't actually implement it now, I'm always looking to improve my TeX knowledge, so I'm genuinely grateful! :)

Comment: @SamT - I've posted an addendum to (gently, hopefully) question your claim that using `\widetilde` on uppercase-letter variable names in inline mode somehow increases the line spacing. This claim should only ever be true if the value of baselineskip is unusually small (in which case there will be lots of other problems with the document...).

Comment: (Sorry, only just seen this!) Interesting point. However, I've just tested it, and if I have `\tfrac12` (or `\frac12`) on the previous line, then using `\widetilde` *does* increase the vertical linespacing: however, `\tilde` does too, just not by so much. \\ Note also in your example at one point how close the `\widetilde` is to the comma above it; it's not as bad with the usual `\tilde`.

Comment: @SamT - It looks like you're trying to shift the conversation by introducing new evidence which wasn't available so far. (Up until now, you only mentioned accents placed *above* symbols.) I believe my earlier main recommendation -- *not* to switch between `\tilde` and `\widetilde` depending on whether the variable ("`X`", say) occurs in display or text situations -- is still appropriate. For fractional expressions, there is a well-known, clear-cut recommendation: *don't* write `\frac{a}{b}`; instead, use "inline fraction notation", i.e., `a/b`. You can look this up in the TeXbook if you wish.

Comment: @SamT - Regarding your other comment, about the proximity of the widetilde accent to a comma in the line above it: If this is a real concern in your document, I can only suggest that you increase the baselineskip slightly. E.g., if the main font size is 10pt and the default baselineskip is 12pt, consider increasing it to 13pt. This is not just a theoretical recommendation; this was exactly what was done for the math textbook "Concrete Mathematics", by Graham, Knuth, and Patashnik. I continue to believe that switching from widetilde to tilde for inline math material would be a mistake.

Comment: Thanks for your response :) -- I don't really understand what you mean "by shifting the conversation" though: I was talking about documents in general, and previous lines aren't necessarily just text or above-accents. I don't know what the TeXbook is, but could you give me a reference to your recommendation for inline fractions? *Personally,* I find them aesthetically very unappealing, but I'm interested in other people's views! Similarly with increasing the baselineskip: I find this gives an unpleasant look, but others may not

Comment: (Incidentally, I do still agree with your recommendation of *not* swapping between wide and standard tilde, as I mentioned on the other answers. I am appreciative for your answer, still, as it helps me learn more about TeX so in the future I can do these things myself without having to call upon the experts on here! :)

Comment: @SamT - *The TeXbook* is the title of a book (about TeX — surprise!) by Donald E. Knuth. “Who is Donald E. Knuth?”, I can here you ask. The creator of TeX, as well as an all-around seriously famous mathematician and math educator. Any decent library should have a copy of this book. Check out, in particular, the chapters about math typesetting.

Answer (score 4):

Your conditional setting can be achieved using [`\mathchoice`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/148740/5764), which easily distinguishes between math in the various (four) styles:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\vartilde}[1]{
  \mathchoice
    {\widetilde{#1}}% \displaystyle
    {\tilde{#1}}% \textsyle
    {\tilde{#1}}% \scriptstyle
    {\tilde{#1}}% \scriptscriptstyle
}

\begin{document}

Reference: $\tilde{X}\ \widetilde{X}$

Consider
\[
  \tilde{X} \quad \vartilde{X} \quad \widetilde{X}
\]
where $\vartilde{X}$ changes with the math style.

\end{document}
```

Note how the above example also shows the drawback of using the varied display. The symbol (or notation) doesn't remain the same when used in the different styles next to one another, which might not be ideal.

Comment: Thanks very much. I wouldn't use `\tilde` and `\vartilde` in display mode. The idea would be to only use `\vartilde`.

Comment: Given that both egreg and Mico, who each have an enormous amount of experience, have recommended against doing using such a variation, I think I'll probably not implement it. Thank you for your answer, however. I'm always trying to learn more about TeX, so I am genuinely appreciative :)

Comment: @SamT: They're both presented as reference.