# Shorten notation in Math mode

Tags: math-mode

Consider the following math mode notation: `\bar{\Delta)}`

Is there anyway I make this simpler. Say I want to type `\bd` and get `\bar{\Delta)}`. How can I do that?

Comment: I know this is a question that must have been asked 1000 times in all kinds of places, but I simply don't know what to google

Comment: You *could* use `\newcommand{\bd}{\bar{\Delta)}}` but really shouldn't. Use keyboard short cuts instead, your collaborators will appreciate it.

Comment: In a few months, @k.dkhk may be asking [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/496660/replace-all-shorthands-defined-by-newcommand-with-full-commands)...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here my same proposal of the best user @marmot. You can create a specific short macro.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\newcommand{\bd}{\bar{\Delta}}

\begin{document}
\[\bd\]
\end{document}
```