# Using macros to do typesetting, and then delete them from source code for others?

Tags: macros, formatting, compiling

I am currently using LyX for my mathematical typesetting, and I really like the macro functionality. However, I can imagine that the source code from such an output must be a pain for others to look at if I produce a document in this way.

I am curious to know if there is an analogue of "compact history" with any LaTeX output that arises from macros? Consider the following minimal example (with the preamble and document begin/end declarations removed):

```
\global\long\def\testMacroA#1{{\color{red}#1}}%
\global\long\def\testMacroB#1{\tilde{#1}}%
\global\long\def\testMacroC#1{\underrightarrow{#1}}%

$\testMacroA{\testMacroB{\testMacroC A}}$
```

Is there anything in LaTeX that can be used to remove any trace of the original macros and replace any instances of them with the code that they represent, so that when the source code is compiled, it simply gives

```
${\color{red}\tilde{\underrightarrow{A}}}$ ?
```

Comment: If you use `\def` seems difficult, but for `\newcommand` there are some tools. [programming - Is there a script that reads a TeX file and replaces every instance of a \newcommand? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67709/is-there-a-script-that-reads-a-tex-file-and-replaces-every-instance-of-a-newcom?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Doesn't work in all cases though. It's **extremely difficult** to write such a tool, but if you restrict yourself to a subset of TeX you should be fine using de-macro or some Python/perl script as the linked question above..

Comment: Please always add [links to crossposts](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=35281) at all crossposts.